# get specific data from bs4 element tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to get data from a website. I am using the *select* method to perform a CSS selection operation. But i can't extract the value i want.

This is my code:

```
data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.content,'lxml')
html_PER = data.select('tr[title="Price to Earnings Ratio Basico"]')`
```

this i what i get:

```
[<tr title="Price to Earnings Ratio Basico">
 <td>PER Basico:</td>
 <td align="right">
 <span class="cash daily" data-decimals="2" data-format="%s%v" data-suffix="" data-symbol="">16,53639823662936</span>
 </td>
 </tr>]
```

I would like to extract the 16.53 value. But I don't know how.

I'm sure there is a easiest way to do this. But I'm new in web scraping and I don't know nothing about html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector:

```
td > span.cash.daily
```

on the result `html_PER` elements.

So, you can do:

```
values = [tr.select_one('td > span.cash.daily').text for tr in html_PER]
```

---

Note that, when you know that there would be only one tag element, use `select_one` instead of `select` to get a faster response by breaking out early after the first match.